# How to use string of <li> in django view?

Tags: python, html, django, ajax

I am building a blog where users can click on several `<li>` items in the sidebar to show blog posts according to the clicked category.

The desired outcome is somewhat to the official [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/), so that I will end up with `/blog/category` and the according blog posts rendered.

The problem is that if I visit the main page (or http://127.0.0.1:8000/ in development) it raises an error

```
render_blog() missing 1 required positional argument: 'category'
```

So how can I use the view `render_blog` both for the main page and for the categories clicked to render the according blog posts?

**html**

```
<li class="navigation-item" id="spotlights-item">
    <div id="spotlights-ctn"><a href="/HotStocks">Hot Stocks</a><img id="fire-icon" src="{% static 'images/fire.svg' %}" alt="finsphere.io"></div>
</li>
```

**urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('AsiaPacific/<category>', render_blog, name='AsiaPacific'),
    url(r'^$', render_blog, name='render_blog'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def render_blog(request, category):
        category = category

        if not category:
            # Main blog as landing page
            # Get 5 latest posts and order by publish date, newest first
            posts = Post.objects.filter(publish_date__lte=now).order_by('-publish_date')[:5]
            return render(request, 'blog/blog.html', {'posts': posts})
        else:
            # Blog displayed as Category Selection
            posts = Post.objects.filter(categories__title=category, publish_date__lte=now)
            return render(request, 'blog/blog.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Comment: Hi, I have a suggestion. why can't you pass variable (load more link)via href <a href="{% url 'lazy_load_posts' category %}">load more</a> in your case pass value in ajax, and check condition in view using if. That is possible, right? No need to write a new function every time. It's just a suggestion.

Comment: @SaranPrasad Thank you for your input, but I cant follow your idea :-x

Comment: You need to pass a variable along with ajax call and check variable value in the view. You're maintaining different html pages right? So you easily done that. In category section ajax call pass a value like category. You need to identify this for category in load function redirect the it category model set using if condition.

Comment: but the initial queryset isn't ajax based, so how to pass a variable to the view when clicking an anchor tag link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not 100% sure I'm following, but you don't have to use the href on an anchor tag to link anywhere. You can just set href="" and give every link a class such as "category-link". Then tie your ajax onclick event to the class, and have the code first pull the text or another attribute from the link and submit it as a variable:

```
$('.category-link').on('click', function() {
  var link = $(this);
  var page = link.data('page');
  var category = link.data('category');
  $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: '/lazy_load_posts/',
      data: {
         'page': page,
         'category': category,
         'csrfmiddlewaretoken': window.CSRF_TOKEN // from blog.html
      },
  (...)
```